# How to create autocompletion for zsh

Tags: zsh-completion

I have a simple command with a couple sub commands which I would like to create a zsh code completion script for. I have read many web sites, but very confused.

My command (and sub commands) are:

```bash
stx ls
stx clean
stx start
stx stop
```

How can I create a code snippet to include in my .zshrc file to do tab completion? I really appreciate your help. I know that SO is not a code writing service, but I have done my research and not getting any closer.

## References

Here are some of the places I have read.

- https://thevaluable.dev/zsh-completion-guide-examples/
- https://dev.to/kumareth/a-beginner-s-guide-for-setting-up-autocomplete-on-ohmyzsh-hyper-with-plugins-themes-47f2
- https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/nm2vun/a_guide_to_the_zsh_autocompletion_with_examples/